# Convert this hex string into array of integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, hex, string-conversion

I am using node.js v6.

I have this hex string;

```
let hex_string = "0102030402";
```

I would like to convert `hex_string` into an array of integer `array_hex_integer` that looks like this;

```
let array_hex_integer;
array_hex_integer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2];
```

The first element in `array_hex_integer` corresponds to '01' (1st and 2nd chars) in `hex_string`, 2nd element corresponds to '02' (3rd and 4th chars) in `hex_string` and so on.

Comment: good luck with that

Answer (score 6):

Here is one possible way to do what you need.

```
var hex_string = "0102030402";
var tokens = hex_string.match(/[0-9a-z]{2}/gi);  // splits the string into segments of two including a remainder => {1,2}
var result = tokens.map(t => parseInt(t, 16));
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hozzsn?file=index.js

Comment: Upvoted. Although my answer was selected as the answer, I think your answer is much better than my long-winded answer. Brilliant :)

Comment: Upvoted as well, although it does not work completely yet with real hexa:
1) the regexp should be `/../g` or `/[0-9a-z]{2}/gi`,
2) and `parseInt(t, 16)` should specify the radix.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript I use this function to convert hexstring to unsigned int array

```
function hexToUnsignedInt(inputStr) {
  var hex  = inputStr.toString();
  var Uint8Array = new Array();
  for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
    Uint8Array.push(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
  }
  return Uint8Array;
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

First, split `hex_string` into an array of string. See my function `split_str()`. Then, convert this array of string into the array of integer that you want.

```
function split_str(str, n)
{
    var arr = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += n)
    {
        arr.push(str.substr(i, n));
    }
    return arr;
}

function convert_str_into_int_arr(array_str)
{
    let int_arr = [];
    for (let i =0; i < array_str.length; i++)
    {
        int_arr [i]=parseFloat(array_str[i]);
    }

    return int_arr;
}

let answer_str = split_str(hex_string,10);
let answer_int = convert_str_into_int_arr(answer_str);
```